# Was Harry tethered to life as long as Voldemort lived with Harry's blood in him, or was he only safe from attack from Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, lily-potter

In the chapter King's Cross of Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Dumbledore explains that Harry didn't die because:

> "He took your blood and rebuilt his living body with it! Your blood in his veins, Harry, Lily's protection inside both of you! He tethered you to life while he lives!"

Does this mean that Harry was in fact never in danger from dying as long as this incarnation of Voldemort lived, or was he only protected from dying at Voldemort's hand?